# Matching partial view td properties to column headings

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a table that is in a partial view (for updating when paging etc...)

now I have a select tag with some options like summary, created date, created by, ledger, customer etc... and there are several of these select tags(one for every column in the table) they all contain the same values.
I have a Model (Account) and a list of these objects is returned to be used in my partial view...the problem/my question is that when I am displaying the data, how do I know which property to use under the heading?

I was thinking of writing some methods or a new class that matched the headings from the drop downs to the properties names in the model or vice versa and used those in the view, the class to would possibly have a dictionary of mappings and some simple methods to map the drop down to the property or vice versa and return the property needed to be displayed.

does anyone have anymore ideas? - It is pretty much heading this way so far.

In my table body I am doing this:

```
<table id="TableOptions">
        <thead>
            <tr id="AffectedHeader">
                @{
                    String[] DropsOptions = Model.SelectedDropsOptions;
                    for (int i = 0; i <= DropsOptions.Length; i++)
                    {
                    <td>
                        <select class="filter" id="@i.ToString()">
                            <option selected="@Model.SelectedDropsOptions[i]">@Model.SelectedDropsOptions[i]</option>
                            @{
                        foreach (String Option in Model.Options)
                        {
                                <option>@Option</option>
                        }   
                            }
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    }
                }
            </tr>
        </thead>

List<Management.Models.Account> Accounts = Model.Accounts;
                for (int i = Model.RowFrom; i <= Model.RowTo; i++)
                {
                    if (i % 2 == 0)
                    {
                <tr id="@Accounts[i].Interested_in">
                    <td>@Accounts[i]</td>
                    <td>@Accounts[i]</td>
                    <td>@Accounts[i]</td>
                    <td>@Accounts[i]</td>
                    <td>@Accounts[i]</td>
                    <td>@Accounts[i]</td>
                    <td>@Accounts[i]</td>
                    <td>@Accounts[i]</td>
</tr>
```

the Account Model in each of the tags should have properties that relate to a column. The Model has a property called MappedOptionProperties where the drops options that have been selected are mapped to the property of the Account model. So for each of those I need to get the property but I can't just append them to `@Accounts[i]`

Comment: Post some of your code to give an example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you are getting at. How are you handling the the select changes? Is it a form or are you using ajax to update the rows? Anyway, what I would suggest is that the Accounts model just has a field that holds whatever data that is supposed to be shown. Then you set this field inside the controller depending on the request data (or however you are processing what the user has selected).

Comment: @JuhaKangas Thank you, I ended up getting rid of the properties, using a list of objects inside a list and iterating around those, since it will do it in order of the columns selected I can iterate straight through and output them, I guess I was overcomplicating it.